# Glogg - Is Similar in Java is Possible or any Java alternative

Tags: java

Glogg https://github.com/nickbnf/glogg is very faster in searching and displaying the results even when the file size is in GBs

How to achieve this in java displaying the content quickly in swing and displaying the search results?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been developing a fork of glogg for several years. The main trick behind glogg's performance is building an index mapping a line number to an offset inside the file. This index is then used to read a block of lines and pass it to regular expressions search engine. So all file reading is done in big chunks that utilizes IO very well. My [fork](https://github.com/vairar/klogg) adds some multi-threading support and uses hyperscan library for regex matching that is much faster than the one that ships with Qt. I think that can be reimplemented in Java and it can be even faster with less copying of string data.